# How to insert a new HTML syntax after onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to change the content in Container element after clicking on a button that calls the `characterClicked` function and the new element should maintain the styles of the `characterElement`?

```
class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({characters: data.results}))
  }

  state = {
    characters: [],
    displayCharacter: []
  }

  characterClicked = (name) => {
    const { characters, displayCharacter } = this.state
    this.setState({ characters: characters })
    let popUpCharacter = characters.find(character => character.name === name)
    let showUpElement = 
    `<CharacterElement key={index} name=${popUpCharacter.name} >
      <h2>${popUpCharacter.name}</h2>
      <p>Birth year: ${popUpCharacter.birth_year}</p>
      <p>height: ${popUpCharacter.height} cm</p>
      <p>Mass: ${popUpCharacter.mass} kg</p>
    </CharacterElement>`
    document.querySelector(Container).innerHTML = showUpElement
  }

  render() {
    const { characters } = this.state
    return (
      <div style={main}>
        <Aside  characterClicked={this.characterClicked} />
        <Container>
          {characters.map( (character, index) =>
            <CharacterElement key={index} name={character.name} >
              <h2>{character.name}</h2>
              <p>Birth year: {character.birth_year}</p>
              <p>height: {character.height} cm</p>
              <p>Mass: {character.mass} kg</p>
            </CharacterElement>
          )}
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }

const CharacterElement = styled.div`
  background-color: #0d141c;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
`

}
```

Comment: From your question, is the content changing after you click the button? What is not working? Rerendering the element with new content or styling the new element?

Comment: Naturally, the content is changing after click the button as I want, but CharacterElement is not stylized like in case of  render method

Comment: Could you share you code in  jsfindle or something similar?

Comment: Please share your code in any online snipping tools platforn that will help us to figure out the actual problem.